# Can you take a thread dump of a non-java process?

Tags: multithreading, apache, rhel

I have done quite a bit of research, and cant find any documentation on this. I may be using the wrong terminology with the term "thread dump", so I apologize for any lack of knowledge on this topic.

I am looking for a way to take a thread dump of an Apache webserver running on an RHEL AWS instance. The Apache webserver is running on the httpd process. From my understanding, tools like jstack and jmap are specific to taking thread dumps of JVM processes only, and httpd is not compatible.

When I use `ps -aux | grep apache` I receive the following output of processes.

> ps -aux | grep apache
> ssm-user  1539  0.0  0.0 112812   960 pts/1    S+   17:26   0:00 grep apache
> apache    1554  0.0  0.2 272752 15488 ?        S    16:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache    1713  0.0  0.1 270376 13452 ?        S    16:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache    1715  0.0  0.1 270376 13452 ?        S    16:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache    1956  0.0  0.1 270556 14080 ?        S    13:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache    5700  0.0  0.2 272752 15704 ?        S    May22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache    5701  0.0  0.2 272996 16064 ?        S    May22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache    5703  0.0  0.1 270676 14368 ?        S    May22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache    5704  0.0  0.2 272720 15636 ?        S    May22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache   11441  0.0  0.2 272776 15744 ?        S    04:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
> apache   11442  0.0  0.2 272800 15832 ?        S    04:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

I am also unsure why there are so many of the same process, but I wanted to figure out if its possible to take a thread dump of one of the processes before I dive into solving the duplicate processes.

Are there any tools or commands I can use to accomplish a thread dump of an httpd process?

Comment: Please describe what you exactly means by "thread dump". A thread is basically just a stack and few register states. Is this what you want to dump?

Comment: Yes this sounds like the correct information I want to dump. I want to dump the httpd process similar to what jstack does for a java process where it lists all the different processes and states.